# how to code a PHP function who will check whether the mode of Apache is on safemode or not?

Tags: php, apache, safe-mode

how to code a PHP function who will check whether the mode of Apache is on safemode or not ?

Comment: yes that's what i meant...hahaha sorry i don't know the detail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php 
// Check for safe mode
if( ini_get('safe_mode') ){
    // Do it the safe mode way
}else{
    // Do it the regular way
}

?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php#45263

Answer (score 3):

Apache doesn't have a safemode, Do you mean PHP?

```
$safemode = ini_get('safe_mode');
```